# Elementary Row (and Column) Operations over field Q.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am asked to find the inverse of a matrix A in M3x3(Q).

Finding the inverse of a matrix over F, Z1, Z2, etc. is straightforward for me, but I have never done such a problem over the field Q and I'm struggling to see how the process would differ from solving the system over F.

If I were to reduce (A|I) into (I|A^-1) as if it were over the field F instead of Q, how different would my answer be? If someone could help me understand how to row-reduce over Q it would help me a lot.

Thanks!

Comment: Weird question. What exactly is the problem with computing the inverse matrix over $\mathbb{Q}$? What confuses you?

Comment: what is Z1 and Z2 ?

Comment: @kabenyuk  I'm confused about how my matrix computations will change over Q as opposed to over F. E.g. R1 = [1 2 3] and R2 = [2 3 4] are two rows of a matrix over F. I subtract 2(R1) from R2 to get R2' = [0 -1 -2].  How would this result have changed if the matrix were over Q? I hope my question is clearer.

Comment: @cineel Z2 = {0,1}; Z3 = {0,1,2}; etc.

Comment: @RanRajmirsen Please tell me what $Q$ is and what $F$ is. Otherwise it is impossible to understand you.

Comment: @kabenyuk sorry. Q is rational numbers; F is real numbers